# Rotating watch hands, not working....

Tags: modeling

Trying to rotate watch hands using an Empty, but no matter what I try, the hand rotates on a weird axis alignment.

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried Parent, Parent Keep Transform, Inverse Parent.
I've tried applying Rotation to the object before parenting and still same issue.
Apply rotation to the empty before parent, just does this weird axis flipping thing.

Thanks,
alldaron

[image]
[image]

Comment: blend file on dropbox:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g211oqyzvtnvljv/HANDS.blend?dl=0

Comment: .... animate the rotation of the watch hands...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bone instead of the empty to control the hand, just rotate it in ***object mode*** to match the hand axis rotation , when you parent the hand to the bone, choose bone in the ***set parent to*** menu, then when animating the bone, make sure to do it in ***pose mode***

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the reply; yes, this is how i rotate it for initial posing, but when I try to animate the rotation over 24 frames by placing keyframes at frame 1 and 24 for rotate, then press play, the animation doesn't adhere to the z-rotation.

Comment: example video here: https://youtu.be/5XFYyhyLpVk

Comment: Just reset the rotation of all objects, add a 'master' empty, parent the dial and the controlling empty (the one that controlls the hands) to it, animate it at its default position, then you can rotate the 'master' empty to change the whole clock rotation

Comment: awesome thanks, one last question, is there any way to do this without resetting the rotations, since the scene is already posed.

Comment: I edited my answer, also here's a file with both methods used

http://www.mediafire.com/file/aun1wvukaa5tejj/HANDS.zip